# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getMccString()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: android, kotlin, telephony, telephonymanager

I am retrieving cell information data (`CellInfo`) from `TelephonyManager`

For each cell info object, I am querying for *mcc* (Mobile Country Code) and *mnc* (Mobile Network Code) via

```
eachCellInfo.cellIdentity.mcc
eachCellInfo.cellIdentity.mnc
```

Where eachCellInfo is an object of [CellInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfo)

The function is deprecated as per the doc:

```
    /**
     * @return 2 or 3-digit Mobile Network Code, 0..999, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown
     * @deprecated Use {@link #getMncString} instead.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public int getMnc() {
        return (mMncStr != null) ? Integer.valueOf(mMncStr) : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
```

However when I am using the suggested method that is via

```
    eachCellInfo.cellIdentity.mccString
```

Method Description:

```
        /**
         * @return Mobile Country Code in string format, null if unknown
         */
        public String getMccString() {
            return mMccStr;
        }
```

I am getting following crash logs:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getMccString()Ljava/lang/String; in class Landroid/telephony/CellIdentityLte; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.telephony.CellIdentityLte' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
 )
```

Let me know if I am missing any information and possible cause of this behavior.

Other Infor:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip 
kotlin_version = '1.3.21' 
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
Debug Version
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
```

Comment: What's your Gradle version?

Comment: Please check edits
@ZUNJAE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method was introduced in Android api 28 - check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityTdscdma.html#getMccString()) - which means it won't be available in versions before.

This will work on devices running api 28+ and will throw that exception in devices running lower api levels.

Usually the correct way to do this is to introduce checks for the version:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
   // Safe to use getMccString
} else {
   // Use something else that could work if there's something
}
```

Note that just because you can browse the source in your machine it doesn't mean the device running your app will have the same Android code running - most of the time it doesn't.

Comment: I hope java doc related to this must say something like RequireApi so that we can handle it at compile time. Thanks Anyways