# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getTextBounds Error in android

Tags: java, android, textview, android-paint

When I try to use the `getTextBounds()` method of `Paint` class in Android, I am getting errors on older version emulators (Marshmallow and Nougat 7.1.1). This is the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getTextBounds(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;IILandroid/graphics/Rect;)V in class Landroid/graphics/Paint; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.graphics.Paint' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

The issue does not seem to happen on android 10 emulator. I tried Invalidating caches and restarting as suggested in another answer, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

When I use

```
Paint.getTextBounds(@NoNull CharSequence text, int start, int end, @NoNull Rect bounds);
```

some devices throws

```
error:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getTextBounds
```

replace:

```
Paint.getTextBounds(@NoNull String text, int start, int end, @NoNull Rect bounds);
```

it works
hope help U

Answer (score 1):

This method was introduced in Android api 28 - check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityTdscdma.html#getMccString()) - which means it won't be available in versions before.

This will work on devices running api 28+ and will throw that exception in devices running lower api levels.

Usually the correct way to do this is to introduce checks for the version:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
// Safe to use getMccString
} else {
// Use something else that could work if there's something
}
```

Note that just because you can browse the source in your machine it doesn't mean the device running your app will have the same Android code running - most of the time it doesn't.

as mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767020/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-virtual-method-getmccstringljava-lang-string)

Comment: So, is there any recommended method to do this pre 28? I only need the width of the text

Comment: Study Android source code, Paint.java source, see both measureText and getTextBounds methods. You'd learn that measureText calls native_measureText, and getTextBounds calls nativeGetStringBounds, which are native methods implemented in C++.